# SQL Queries with xPath Expressions for finding similar values

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath

This uses oracle database to store the data using the XML type, I was wondering is there any way to do a query to output the name of the people of who are swimmer and teachers? probably alot easier than i think

```
<swimmer>
<swimmer name>John Goldrick</swimmer name>
<swimmer name>James John</swimmer name>
<teacher>
<teacher name>John Goldrick</teacher name>
</swimmer>
</teacher>
```

Comment: You mean they are both swimmer and teacher?

Comment: Yeah, so how could i do a query to output the name of the person who is a swimmer and teacher?

Comment: This isn't even valid XML.

Comment: I was just using it as an example, I was just wondering how do to see if both of the attributes were the same. Is it something like:  
/swimmer[swimmername =/teacher/teachername]?